# Maven WebResources files becoming directory in war file

Tags: maven, overriding, webresource

My project has two version for two different client. Both version have some common files with different content. So I have replaced common files in war file in war using WebResource under war plugin. This files becomes directory in war file when I run maven in linux. Project work fine in windows environment.

Comment: Can you share any code or configuration files? Also, please clarify do you mean that what you are doing works in Windows but you are getting an error in Linux?

Comment: Suppose log4j.properties file have two version for two client. I have pointed the directory for log4j.properties and output directory under webresources in war plugin. When war is built log4j.properties become a directory in war. copy resources phase working fine but while copying for war file then all files become directory in war.